# Firebug won't let me select a script file

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Firefox 13.0.1 with Firebug 1.9.2.

I load a page with Firebug activated. I select the Script tab. This page loaded multiple script files, and the script tab shows the first one on the list (which happens to be JQuery). So far, so good. I go to the menu with all the scripts, and I select the one I want to look at. It shows this script for about half a second, then switches back to JQuery.

This happens every time, but only on the page that I'm working on right now, and only with one particular script file. There aren't any error messages.

Anybody have any ideas?

---

Update: The problem appears tied to one line in the script file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...

    // If I remove this, the problem goes away:
    setInterval("foo()", 1000) 

})
```

Comment: I have no direct answer, but you need somehow to trace firebug log to see what happens

Comment: I looked around a bit. looks like u need to get your hand dirty with their code. http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/hacking-on-firebug/

Comment: Just as a diagnostic check, what happens if you temporarily replace everything in that file with `//test` ... do you get the same behavior?

Comment: also try to call that file directly in browser to see if its reachable

Comment: @machineghost : If I comment everything in the file, then the file disappears from the menu, so I can't even select it.

Comment: Side note (or maybe not): use `setInterval(foo, 1000) ` instead of `setInterval("foo()", 1000)`. The second version when you pass a string is considered harmful, because internally it invokes `eval` which adds overhead and reduces possibility of throwing instant JS syntax error (in case `foo` does not exist, you have a typo etc.) until the time of the first execution.

Comment: Take a look at the Firefox Error Console. SHIFT+CTRL+J